# Solve a system of ODEs?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am a new Mathematica user. I solved the homogeneous equation **ydot = A y** analytically, using mathematica alpha command **Y' = [{-3, 2}, {-1, -6}] Y**

My question consists of two parts:

a) Is there any command to simplify the output? it sound nicer when solved by hand (but takes forever).

b) How to plot the output in Mathematica?

Comment: `Y' = [{-3, 2}, {-1, -6}] Y` isn't actual Mathematica code, so it's not clear what you mean when you say you solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [DSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html) in the documentation center.

```
a = {{-3, 2}, {-1, -6}};
eqns = Thread[{y1'[x], y2'[x]} ==  a.{y1[x], y2[x]}];

solution = DSolve[eqns, {y1[x], y2[x]}, x];
solution // FullSimplify
```

> `{{y1[x] -> E^(-5 x) (-C[1] - 2 C[2] + 2 E^x (C[1] + C[2])), 
>     y2[x] -> E^(-5 x) (C[1] + 2 C[2] - E^x (C[1] + C[2]))}}`

```
solution[[1]] // FullSimplify // Column // TraditionalForm //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \text{y1}(x)\to e^{-5 x} \left(-c_1-2 c_2+2 e^x \left(c_1+c_2\right)\right) \\
>  \text{y2}(x)\to e^{-5 x} \left(c_1+2 c_2-e^x \left(c_1+c_2\right)\right) \\
> \end{array}$

```
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[x], y2[x]} /. solution /. {C[1] -> 3, C[2] -> 5}], 
 {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 10}]
```

[image]

Explore the solution for different initial values:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{y1[x], y2[x]} /. solution /. {C[1] -> d[[1]], C[2] -> d[[2]]}], 
  {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 10}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"initial values:" , d}]], 
{{d, {2, 4}, "initial values"}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just have one more question: I tried to copy/paste the plot command "Plot[Evaluate[{y1[x], y2[x]} /. solution /. {C[1] -> 3, C[2] -> 5}], 
 {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 10}]", but it gives me several errors, what should I replace ./solution/. with? Sorry, but I am a new user of mathematica :) thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Omar, what kind of errors are you getting? Can you post an example?

Comment: ReplaceAll::reps: {solution} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. 
ReplaceAll::reps: {solution} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Comment: @Omar, in version 9 the code works as is. Do you get the same error if you use `...  /. solution[[1]] ... ` instead of `... /.  solution ...`?

Comment: Plot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. solution[[1]] /. {C[1] -> 3.15, 
    C[2] -> 6.2}], {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]

Comment: I tried it, no more errors, but the graph is empty. just the x,y axes. please, any suggestion? thank you :)

Comment: @Omar, try `ClearA[[, x, y1, y2, a, eqns, solution]` before all of your code. Or start from a fresh kernel (i.e. restart Mathematica , or use `Quit Kernel` in the `Evaluation` menu on the top bar).

Comment: That was very helpful! thanks a lot. may I ask you where did you get the values "c1=>3 and c2=> 5" from?

Comment: @Omar, my pleasure.  `3` and `5` just two initial values randomly picked for the sake of illustration. By the way,  it would be useful if you edit your question to correct the syntax error.